# applying different style in table headers

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a table like

```
<table class="historystyle" >
  <tr>
    <th > name</th>
    <th >location</th>
    <th > job</th>
    <tr>
</table>
```

in `name` header i dont want to apply the `background-image` style so i put th inside a div element and set `style="background-image: none;`

But it is not working .name header still shows the `backgorund image`.whats wrong with my code..please help

```
<table class="historystyle" >
  <tr>
   <th><div style="background-image: none; ">name</div></th>
    <th>location</th>
    <th> job</th>
    <tr>
</table>
```

style

```
.historystyle th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url(../images/bg.gif);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: get rid of the useless div and just do `<th style="background-image: none;">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply your `style="background-image: none"` to the `th` itself:

```
<table class="historystyle" >
  <tr>
   <th style="background-image: none">name</th>
    <th>location</th>
    <th> job</th>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Applying it to the `div` has no impact on how the `th` is displayed. By default, (most) HTML elements are transparent, so the `div` would have no background, but you could see right through to the `th`, which did still have a background.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your second `tr` tag should be `/tr`. Now try the following CSS code:

```
/* your style code */
.historystyle th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url(../images/bg.gif);
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* add this */
.historystyle th:first-of-type {
    background-image: none;
}
```

This makes the first occuring `th` element within `.historystyle` appear without a background image. I made a quick test to verify that this works [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelvandeWeerd/LLpwW/), using background colors instead of images.